# How to type a `tensorflow.data.Dataset`

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, python-typing

I have some functions that accept instances of `tensorflow.data.Dataset`. I would like to type those functions so that the caller knows what is expected. However, doing `data: Dataset`, is not good enough, because people wouldn't know what kind of structure is produced by the object (shape of tensors, whether is tuple or dictionary, etc).

There is another object, `tensorflow.data.DatasetSpec`, which can be used to document the objects that will be produces by the `tensorflow.data.Dataset`. However, I am not sure how to put those things together for a typing annotation, and I am left to describe the structure in docstring, which I do not think is ideal.

I would love to see something like a generic, where you pass the type it accepts, like `Dataset[Spec]`(like in lists we do `List[int]`), but I am happy to learn some other ways to achieve more descriptive typing than just `data: tf.data.Dataset`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an option, you may use [tf function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function), which has `input_signature` argument.

Comment: That would be the case if I wanted to compile a function into something I can call from the graph, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough then to just do something like `def function( var1:  Tuple[ TensorSpec(...), TensorSpec(...), ...  ], var2: ... )` ? This compiles. If you want, you may wrap this with `tf.data.DatasetSpec` appropriately.